# The equilibrium value in ergodic quantum Dual Unitary circuits

Tags: thermodynamics

In the paper from [Felix Fritzsch & Tomaž Prosen (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.11694), it's mentioned that the ergodic (dual unitary) circuit has an equilibrium value of order $q^{−2L}$.

> At large times autocorrelation functions are expected to equilibrate, i.e.,
> they oscillate around their long-time average with both the oscillations and the equilibrium value of order **$q^{−2L}$**.

But instead, in paper from [Bruno Bertini & Pavel Kos, Tomaz Prosen (2019)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02140) and summarized by [Pieter W. Claeys & Austen Lamacraft(2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.03791), it's said the value should be exactly zero.

> As argued in Ref. [16], the long-time behaviour of all nontrivial correlations and hence the level of ergodicity is fully determined by the number of eigenvalues $λ_{ab}$ of $M_±$ with unit modulus, $|λab| = 1$, with the corresponding eigenoperators acting as non-decaying modes, where we exclude the trivial eigenvalue $1$ corresponding to the identity operator. At long times, ergodic behaviour is evidenced by the convergence of correlations to their thermal value **$\lim_{t \to ∞} C_{ρσ}(±t, t) = tr(σ)/q$**, consistent with thermalization to an infinite-temperature Gibbs state ρ_{Gibbs} = 1/q such that $\lim_{t \to ∞} C_{ρσ}(±t, t) = tr(ρ_{Gibbs}σ)$, $∀σ$.

In which $tr(σ)/q$ is exactly zero since σ is traceless.

So my question is 1)why don't the two statements agree with each other. And 2) why does the equilibrium value has form of $q^{−2L}$.

Here are three possibilities I think of, but I can't find any evidence to proof them. I did try a simulation to calculate the correlator via the formula provided in the last paper. The result showed that the equilibrium value of ergodic circuits is indeed zero. But since the first paper I mentioned didn't tell us how the simulation is done, so I'm not sure what I did is a valid proof.

1. The value $q^{−2L}$ is come from the error in quantum circuits in numerical simulation
2. The value $q^{−2L}$ is come from the dual unitary gates which have only seven significant digits
3. $q^{−2L}$ does not exist